# Obtener un array de Strings de un JSONObject en Java

Tags: java, array, json, jsonobject

Desde mi aplicación Java estoy conectandome con MongoDB el cual debe recuperar un JSON de este estilo:

```
{
        "_id": 4,
        "Nombre": {"pila":"JUAN",
                "AP":"PEREZ",
                "AM":"BARROSO"},
        "RFC": "GORM680121MTSNDG06",
        "Sueldo": 32000,
        "Sexo":"MASCULINO",
        "Materias": ["FISICA","QUIMICA"],
        "Telefonos":{ "casa":"4919203601",
                    "celular":"6103926139"}
}
```

El problema es que no sé como obtenerlo con JSONObject, esto es lo que tengo en Java:

```
String id= txtId.getText();
if(id.length()==0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingresa el ID del profesor a buscar");
}
else{
        Conexion con=new Conexion();
        MongoClient mongo=con.crearConexion();
        if(mongo != null){
                MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("Escolar");
                MongoCollection<Document> colec = database.getCollection("profesores"); 
            
                Integer ID= Integer.valueOf(id);
                StringBuilder info = new StringBuilder();
                Document docBusc = new Document("_id",ID);
                MongoCursor<Document> docsResult = colec.find(docBusc).iterator();
                //Iterate over the results printing each document
                String resultado=null;
                while(docsResult.hasNext()){
                    info.append(docsResult.next().toJson());
                }
                mongo.close();
                
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(info.toString());
                System.out.println(jo.get("Materias"));
                String materias = jo.getString("Materias");
                String Materias = "Materias= "+materias+"\n";

                txtResult.setText(Materias);
        }
}
```

Cuando imprimo las materias con `System.out.println(jo.get("Materias"));` imprime **["FISICA","QUIMICA"]**
Pero no lo puedo pasar a una variable String porque es un Objeto y no puedo pasar un Objeto a un arreglo de Strings, nomas en internet me aparece como convertir una array de objetos a un array de Strings

- Si pongo `String materias = jo.getString("Materias");` me sale un error que *JSONObject["Materias"] is not a string.*
- Si pongo `String [] materias = jo.getString("Materias");` me aparece un mensaje que dice : *incompatible types: String cannot be converted to String[]*

He visto como obtener arrays de JSON con getJSONArray() y objetos con getJSONObject() pero no se para array de Strings

Cualquier duda o aclaración, diganme y lo reviso.
Un saludo y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Puedes intentar imprimir `jo.getJSONArray("Materias")` si tienes ese método? También, ¿qué librería de JSON estás usando? org.json? jackson?

Comment: con `System.out.println(jo.getJSONArray("Materias"));` si imprime el array, pero cuando lo asigno a un array `String [] materias = jo.getJSONArray("Materias");`  me aparece _incompatible types:JSONArray cannot be converted to String_ asi que lo asigne a un JSONArray y lo puse en un for y lo pude meter en un String y concatena, muchas gracias por contestar y por tu respuesta, mu ayudaste mucho, no se porque no se me ocurrio, pense que nomas era para array de objetos tipo json y no para cualquier tipo de array, use la libreria org.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando tu solución, efectivamente `JSONObject#getJSONArray` no es exclusivamente para `JSONObject`, porque para ese punto, el mismo objeto no sabe que contiene. Dicho eso, `JSONArray` posee algunos métodos que son prácticos y te pueden generar un código que haga lo mismo sin iteraciones explícitas.

```java
String[] materias = null;
jo.getJSONArray("Materias").toList().toArray(materias); // toArray es void, asi que no devuelve nada.
```

Eso responde a la pregunta original.

Dicho eso, tu enfoque no es incorrecto ni mucho menos. Esto es solo la alternativa que habia estado pensando inicialmente.

Adicionalmente, `JSONArray` posee una implementacion de `Iterator`, asi que igual podrías hacer lo siguiente y obtener el mismo resultado para tu impresión:

```java
/* Si no requieres tener la cadena en memoria para otra cosa, recomiendo */
System.out.print("Materias = "); // print, no println
jo.getJSONArray("Materias").iterator().forEachRemaining(materia -> 
    System.out.print(materia + ", ") 
);
System.out.println();

/* Pero si si la vas a necesitar, puedes hacer esto tambien */
String output = "Materias = ";
jo.getJSONArray("Materias").iterator().forEachRemaining(materia -> 
    output.concat(materia.toString() + ", ") // JSONArray no sabe que contiene, asi que todo lo ve como Object
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Se tiene que usar el metodo getJSONArray() asignandolo a un JSONArray y en un ciclo for voy obteniendo cada elemento del array con el metodo get() en su posicion i y ya lo puedo asignar a un String y concatenarla si yo quiero.

```
String mats="";
JSONArray materias = jo.getJSONArray("Materias");
for(int i = 0; i < materias.length() -1 ; i++){
    mats += materias.get(i)+", ";
    System.out.println(materias.get(i));
}
```

Gracias a la contribucion de @Jetto Martínez porque comento que usara getJSONArray(), pensaba que nomas era para arrays de tipo json como por ejemplo:

```
 {"Pizza": [  
    {
        "nombre": "",
        "masa": "A",
        "ingredientes": [ "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    { 
        "nombre": "",
        "masa": "",
        "ingredientes": [ "", "", "", ""]
    }
]}
```

lo cual aqui si es razonable usar `JSONArray pizzas = menu.getJSONArray("Pizza");`